# How to add a PhoneNumber field in Minicart in magento2

Tags: magento2, php, checkout, ajaxaddtocart, magento2minicart

[image]

[image]

I need to save this phonenumber on quote_item table in phoneno coloumn (I add the extra coloumn through upgradeschema.php). I want to update this phonenumber as how the Quantity of a product is updating by default in magento2

i have these files
app\code\Magelearn\PlusMinusQuantity\etc\module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Magelearn_PlusMinusQuantity" setup_version="2.0.1"/>
</config>
```

app\code\Magelearn\PlusMinusQuantity\registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Magelearn_PlusMinusQuantity',
    __DIR__
);
```

app\code\Magelearn\PlusMinusQuantity\Setup\UpgradeSchema.php

```
<?php
namespace Magelearn\PlusMinusQuantity\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;

class UpgradeSchema implements UpgradeSchemaInterface
{
    public function upgrade(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();

        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '2.0.1', '<')) {
            // Code to run when upgrading to version 2.0.1 or later
            $quoteItemTable = $setup->getTable('quote_item');

            if ($setup->getConnection()->isTableExists($quoteItemTable) == true) {
                $connection = $setup->getConnection();

                $connection->addColumn(
                    $quoteItemTable,
                    'phoneno',
                    [
                        'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                        'nullable' => true,
                        'length' => 255,
                        'comment' => 'Phone Number'
                    ]
                );
            }
        }

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

app\code\Magelearn\PlusMinusQuantity\view\frontend\web\template\minicart\item\default.html

```
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<li class="item product product-item" data-role="product-item">
    <div class="product">
        <!-- ko if: product_has_url -->
        <a data-bind="attr: {href: product_url, title: product_name}" tabindex="-1" class="product-item-photo">
            <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion('itemImage') -->
                <!-- ko template: {name: getTemplate(), data: item.product_image} --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
        </a>
        <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- ko ifnot: product_has_url -->
        <span class="product-item-photo">
            <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion('itemImage') -->
                <!-- ko template: {name: getTemplate(), data: item.product_image} --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
        </span>
        <!-- /ko -->

        <div class="product-item-details">
            <strong class="product-item-name">
                <!-- ko if: product_has_url -->
                <a data-bind="attr: {href: product_url}, html: $parent.getProductNameUnsanitizedHtml(product_name)"></a>
                <!-- /ko -->
                <!-- ko ifnot: product_has_url -->
                    <span data-bind="html: $parent.getProductNameUnsanitizedHtml(product_name)"></span>
                <!-- /ko -->
            </strong>

            <!-- ko if: options.length -->
            <div class="product options" data-mage-init='{"collapsible":{"openedState": "active", "saveState": false}}'>
                <span data-role="title" class="toggle"><!-- ko i18n: 'See Details' --><!-- /ko --></span>

                <div data-role="content" class="content">
                    <strong class="subtitle"><!-- ko i18n: 'Options Details' --><!-- /ko --></strong>
                    <dl class="product options list">
                        <!-- ko foreach: { data: options, as: 'option' } -->
                        <dt class="label"><!-- ko text: option.label --><!-- /ko --></dt>
                        <dd class="values">
                            <!-- ko if: Array.isArray(option.value) -->
                                <span data-bind="html: $parents[1].getOptionValueUnsanitizedHtml(option.value.join('<br/>'))"></span>
                            <!-- /ko -->
                            <!-- ko if: (!Array.isArray(option.value) && ['file', 'html'].includes(option.option_type)) -->
                                <span data-bind="html: $parents[1].getOptionValueUnsanitizedHtml(option.value)"></span>
                            <!-- /ko -->
                            <!-- ko if: (!Array.isArray(option.value) && !['file', 'html'].includes(option.option_type)) -->
                            <span data-bind="text: option.value"></span>
                            <!-- /ko -->
                        </dd>
                        <!-- /ko -->
                    </dl>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /ko -->

            <div class="product-item-pricing">
                <!-- ko if: canApplyMsrp -->

                <div class="details-map">
                    <span class="label" data-bind="i18n: 'Price'"></span>
                    <span class="value" data-bind="i18n: 'See price before order confirmation.'"></span>
                </div>
                <!-- /ko -->
                <!-- ko ifnot: canApplyMsrp -->
                <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion('priceSidebar') -->
                    <!-- ko template: {name: getTemplate(), data: item.product_price, as: 'price'} --><!-- /ko -->
                <!-- /ko -->
                <!-- /ko -->

                <div class="details-qty qty">
                    <label class="label" data-bind="i18n: 'Qty', attr: {
                           for: 'cart-item-'+item_id+'-qty'}"></label>
                    <input data-bind="attr: { id: 'cart-item-'+item_id+'-qty', 'data-cart-item': item_id,  'data-item-qty': qty, 'data-cart-item-id': product_sku}, value: qty"
                            type="number"
                            size="4"
                            class="item-qty cart-item-qty"
                            maxlength="12"/>
                    <button data-bind="attr: { id: 'update-cart-item-'+item_id, 'data-cart-item': item_id, title: $t('Update') }"
                            class="update-cart-item"
                            style="display: none">
                        <span data-bind="i18n: 'Update'"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

            <div class="product actions">
                <!-- ko if: is_visible_in_site_visibility -->
                <div class="primary">
                    <a data-bind="attr: {href: configure_url, title: $t('Edit item')}" class="action edit">
                        <span data-bind="i18n: 'Edit'"></span>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <!-- /ko -->
                <div class="secondary">
                    <a href="#" data-bind="attr: {'data-cart-item': item_id, title: $t('Remove item')}"
                       class="action delete">
                        <span data-bind="i18n: 'Remove'"></span>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="details-phone qty">
    <label class="label" data-bind="i18n: 'Phone Number', attr: {
           for: 'cart-item-'+item_id+'-phone'}"></label>
    <input data-bind="attr: { id: 'cart-item-'+item_id+'-phone', 'data-cart-item': item_id, 'data-cart-item-id': product_sku}, value: $parent.phoneNumber"
            type="tel"
            class="item-phone cart-item-phone"
            maxlength="15"/>
</div>
<button type="button" data-bind="click: updatePhoneNumber">Update</button>

</li>
```

So what next I have to do ?

Answer (score 1):

After adding phone no column in quote_item table and minicart form field, you can follow same steps as update qty for updating phone no in the minicart.

Based on your requirement you may need to override or intercept below core files/functions in your module or theme.

1. Specify phone number update URL in the block Sidebar.php

Reference: vendor/magento/module-checkout/Block/Cart/Sidebar.php

```
public function getConfig()
{
    return [
            .
            .
        'updateItemPhoneNoUrl' => $this->getUpdatePhoneNoUrl()
    ];
}
```

2. Verify serialized array in minicart.phtml

Reference: vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/cart/minicart.phtml

```
$block->getSerializedConfig()
```

3. Add phone number update URL to sidebar widget params in minicart.js

Reference: vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/minicart.js

```
miniCart.sidebar({
    'targetElement': 'div.block.block-minicart',
    'url': {
            .
        'phoneNoUpdate': window.checkout.updateItemPhoneNoUrl,
            .
            .
    },
```

4. Add JS events and logic for mobile number field edit and update via AJAX

Reference: vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/sidebar.js

```
events['keyup ' + this.options.item.phone] = function (event) {
    // your code
};

events['change ' + this.options.item.phone] = function (event) {
    // your code
};
```

5. Write a controller UpdateItemPhoneNo for AJAX to update mobile number for the item

Reference: vendor/magento/module-checkout/Controller/Sidebar/UpdateItemQty.php

```
try {
    ..
    ..
    $this->sidebar->updateItemPhoneNo($itemId, $itemPhoneNo);
    return $this->jsonResponse();
}
.
.
```

6. Pass params to updateItems in Sidebar.php

Reference: vendor/magento/module-checkout/Model/Sidebar.php

```
public function updateItemPhoneNo($itemId, $itemQty)
{
    $itemData = [$itemId => ['phoneno' => $this->normalize($itemPhoneNo)]];
    $this->cart->updateItems($itemData)->save();
    return $this;
}
```

7. Update phone no for the item in Cart.php or observe event checkout_cart_update_items_after

Reference: vendor/magento/module-checkout/Model/Cart.php

```
public function updateItems($data)
{
        .
        .
    $item->setPhoneNo($phoneNo);

        .
        .
}
```

8. Display saved value in the field. Use plugin around getItemData on DefaultItem.

Reference: vendor/magento/module-checkout/CustomerData/AbstractItem.php

Reference: vendor/magento/module-checkout/CustomerData/DefaultItem.php

```
public function getItemData(Item $item)
{
    $this->item = $item;
    return \array_merge(
        ['product_type' => $item->getProductType()],
        $this->doGetItemData()
    );
}
```

Comment: Thankyou LokeshNaik .. I will try